# Derby server connection already exist

Tags: java, connection, derby

In my application I need to check whether the Derby server is already running, and if not start the server. Can anybody tell me how to check that?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is to retrieve a Derby `Connection`. If there's an exception thrown by retrieving the connection, chances are the connection doesn't exist and you can start one.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a 'ping' command available through the NetworkServerControl class: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/publishedapi/jdbc4/org/apache/derby/drda/NetworkServerControl.html